# loading xml with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to run the sample code on W3School
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp

I copied the html+js codes and saved into a html file.
I also downloaded their cd_catalog.xml and put it right beside the html file.

But when I run the html on Chrome, it shows nothing. It is also not working on IE.

Seems the problem is on the line "xmlhttp.send()", because I tried to put an alert right before it, the alert showed, but if I put the alert after that line, then it won't show up.

Anyone can help please?

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd.xml",false);
alert("before");
xmlhttp.send();
alert("after");
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the xml file is on http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml

Comment: copy and paste the edited file too. That could help.

Comment: Check javascript console output in Chrome and/or IE for error description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work if you are running the page as a local file. You need to run it through a webserver (like Apache) in order for the http client/server conversation to work. Can you verify that you are running it through a web server?

Comment: hi @arronfrost - could you tell me, is placing the code on a free hosting site equivalent to running the code on a local web server?

Comment: Yes. As long as the file is being served from the http/https protocol, then it is the same.

Comment: thanks @arronfrost - sorry about the intermittent replies. I am not having any luck with my code on there, is it OK to place all the files in public html dir? Perhaps I should open a question...

Answer (score 0):

@user956159: Please give your extract file location/path in the  `xmlhttp.open`.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/Users/karthik/Desktop/cd_catalog.xml",false);
```

> This is in Mac file path location, I've tested it in my system & it
>   works fine after changing the path of the file.

you can use `"File://users/karthikin/mydocuments/cd_catalog.xml"` or `"File://C:/cd_catalog.xml"` If you are using windows try this in the  `xmlhttp.open`.

The above method to load the files locally, if you want to run through a webserver (like Apache) your code will work exactly.